# Perl LWP trying to set peer_http_version to HTTP/1.0

Tags: perl, http, version, lwp, peer

Getting a 500 server error trying to connect to a Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 server using perl LWP. Can successfully connect using browser. Only difference I see is browser issues HTTP/1.0 protocol vs LWP HTTP/1.1.  So I tried forcing LWP to use the older protocol without success. I found examples for setting this protocol but packet examination with Wireshark still shows HTTP/1.1. What have I missed here. Using Active Perl v5.16.1.

```perl
#! C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(keep_alive=>1);
# trying to force HTTP/1.0
push(@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS, PeerHTTPVersion => "1.0");
my $response = $ua->request(GET "http://google.com");
```

Comment: What browser are you using that's issuing HTTP/1.0 requests?!

Comment: There is no possible way that Firefox is sending HTTP/1.0 requests unless you have manually updated the `network.http.version` config - and I can't think of any reason for someone to do that. 

How are you inspecting these HTTP requests?

Comment: @friedo from Wireshark  <pre>GET / HTTP/1.0

Host: www.google.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1</pre>

Comment: That especially doesn't make sense. HTTP 1.0 does not have a `Host` header.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. My network.http.version is 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make LWP specify HTTP/1.0.

```
my $request = GET "http://google.com";
$request->protocol('HTTP/1.0');
my $response = $ua->request($request);
```